# Basic Segmentation Error

Tags: c++

I have run into an issue of the most simple kind that I cannot seem to resolve.

I have a class called UI, inside UI.h I am storing a single variable called index, and have a method setup(), which sets the value of index:

```
class UI {
public:
  float index;

public:
  void setup(float p_selectedMicrobeIndex);

};
```

With the implementation of setup being:

```
void UI::setup(float p_selectedMicrobeIndex)
{
  microbeIndex = p_selectedMicrobeIndex;
}
```

Inside my game class .h file I am declaring an instance of a class called UI:

```
#include "UI.h"

class Game {
private:

  UI* ui;
};
```

Inside Game.cpp I am running UI.setup() to set the value of index.

```
   ui->setup(0.0f);
```

I am struggling to understand why this results in a segmentation error.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Well is `ui` actually allocated as it's a pointer or are you trying to access an unitialised pointer which would result in an error

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, which OS are you using? I've seen UAE, segmentation faulr, check fault, panic, MAE and am old enough to be confrinted by an ABEND (yes, I am as old as Bilbo). But it's.the first time I see the term "segmentation error". Just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a pointer, but you don't create an instance for it to point to. You should either create an intance

```
UI ui;
ui.setup(0.0f);
```

or do so with a pointer (although I don't see why)

```
UI* ui = new UI;
ui->setup(0.0f);
```

such that the pointer actually points to something sensible.

`UI* ui;` just reserves memory for the pointer to an object of `UI` but no memory for the `UI` object. Thus, the setup fails, because you try to write to not allocated memory.